# Obtener un número aleatorio en JavaScript pero con probabilidad

Tags: javascript, matemáticas

Tengo la siguiente duda, con *JavaScript* puedo obtener un número aleatorio de la siguiente forma:

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

Pero me gustaría meterle probabilidad a cada número, es decir, de un intervalo del 1 al 10 quiero que 5 tenga *tanto porcentaje* de que me aparezca, y lo mismo para otros números. Hasta ahora no encuentro cómo hacerlo.

Comment: y en que parte le meterías la probabilidad? individualmente a cada numero?

Comment: No a todos los números del intervalo, supongamos solo al 5 ( un decir ) o solo al 3 y al 5, o solo al 2, 3 y al 5.  @Sergio1871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución seria, ademas de indicar el rango, pasar a la función una matriz de números "especiales" y sus probabilidades (de 0 a 1).
Entonces, la función, para cada numero "especial" prueba si un numero aleatorio es menor a la probabilidad ( si es 1, siempre sera menor, si es .5 la mitad...) y de serlo, retorna el numero que corresponda.
En caso de no acertar ninguno, retorna un numero aleatorio normal.
En el siguiente ejemplo, busco 100 veces un numero aleatorio de 0 a 10, donde el 0 tiene un .2 y el 5 un .5 de probabilidades de aparecer, y muestro cuantas veces ha aparecido cada numero.

```js
/*  Funcion aleatorioConProbabilidad
      Parámetros de entrada:
        min,max : Rango de números a elegir.
        matrizNumeros : Array con los números con una probabilidad propia.
        matrizProbabilidad : Array con la probabilidad (de 0 a 1) de cada
          número de matrizNumeros.
*/
function aleatorioConProbabilidad (min,max,matrizNumeros,matrizProbabilidad){
 for (let i=0; i<matrizProbabilidad.length; i++)
    /* Prueba números con probabilidad propia, si alguno sale lo retorna. */
  if (Math.random()<matrizProbabilidad[i])
   return matrizNumeros[i];
  /*  Si no ha salido ningún número con probabilidad propia retorna un numero
      aleatorio con probabilidad normal. */
 return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
/*  Prueba de la función: generaremos 100 números aleatorios de 0 a 10
    y contaremos cuantas veces aparece cada número */

/*  Para el contador usaremos una matriz donde en cada posición
    contará las veces que ha salido el número que corresponda a
    la propia posición (en la posición 0 cuenta las veces que aparece el 0,
    en la posición 1 cuanta las veces que aparece el 1...etc)
*/
contador=[];

/*  Como los números son del 0 al 10, la matriz tiene 11 posiciones.*/
contador.length=11;

/*  Inicializamos la matriz con 0's */
contador.fill(0);

/*  Ejecutamos la función 100 veces y incrementa la posición del contador
    que corresponde al numero aparecido. */
for (let i=0; i<100; i++)
  /* Numero aleatorio de 0 a 10 donde el 0 tiene un .2 de salir y el 5 un .5 */
  contador[aleatorioConProbabilidad(0,10,[0,5],[.2,.5])]++;

/*Muestra el contador por consola */
console.log("Veces que ha salido el numero que corresponde a la posicion del siguiente array:");
console.log(contador.toString());
```

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, amigo esto no lo entiendo podrías explicarme? se me hace muy interesante ya que se acerca mucho a la idea

Comment: Como es que si le das un intervalo del 0 al 10 aparecen números mayores al 10?? entonces para que sirve el intervalo "min" y "max", otra pregunta veo que pones 11 numeros `contador.length=11`, pero si yo quiero solo uno por ejemplo `contador.length=1` aparece algo como esto: `26,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN` :) y declaras `var numero;` y jamas lo utilizas :D

Comment: He añadido comentarios en el código, espero que te sirva para comprenderlo mejor.

Answer (score 3):

El comportamiento de `Math.random()` siempre es una función uniforme. Lo que puedes hacer es mapear los intervalos dándoles un porcentaje. En tu ejemplo, si quiero obtener un resultado entre 1 y 3 pero dándole al 2 el doble de probabilidades que al 1 o al 3:

```
function uno_a_tres() {
  // sea n100 un número del 1 al 100 y n3 el resultado de tu función
  var n100 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100+1);

  if(n100<=25) {
    n3 = 1;
  } else if (n100<=75) {
    n3 = 2;
  } else {
    n3 = 3;  
  }
  return n3;
}
```

Como verás, le doy un 50% de probabilidades al 2 y un 25% al 1 y al 3.

Tú podrías generalizar esta función y pasar como parámetro un objeto que contenga cada resultado con su respectiva probabilidad. Eso te queda de tarea porque tiene mayor complejidad: en realidad el rango debiese tener la extensión y la granularidad suficientes como para darle a cada resultado su probabilidad necesaria, y en vez de muchos `if...else` debiese ser un bucle que va recorriendo el objeto sin saber cuántos resultados posibles existen.

PD: La librería [js-weighted-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-weighted-list) ofrece una funcionalidad parecida a lo que te describo, de la forma

```
var data = [['a', 10],  
            ['b',  1],
            ['c',  1],
            ['d',  5],
            ['e',  3]];

var wl = new WeightedList(data);
var result = wl.peek();
```

Comment: un saludo, cuando dices un objeto te refieres como al ejemplo de la librería? algo como 

    `var data = [['a', 10],  
            ['b',  1],
            ['c',  1],
            ['d',  5],
            ['e',  3]];`

Comment: Mi idea de objeto es de tipo llave:valor, esa libreria es un array de parejas, al final es lo mismo

Comment: Ahh Entonces un json no?

Comment: Un json sí, pero json es un formato de texto para describir un objeto en js. También puedes llevar un array, un entero y un string a json si quieres exportarlo o enviarlo a otro lado.

Comment: @IranhCanulMay Objeto en JavaScript se refiere a casi todo, ya que **todos** los tipos de datos heredan el prototipo de [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object) (`Object.prototype`). Solo primitivos no son contados como objetos. Por lo general, cuando se habla de "objetos" en JavaScript se refiere a objetos literales (`{ clave: valor }`).

Answer (score 2):

Una idea que se me ocurre es poner todos los números que quieras en un vector repitiendo varias veces el mismo numero para así se produzca la probabilidad, como ejemplo:

```
function randomConProbabilidad() {

  var numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  var indice = Math.floor(Math.random() * numeros.length);

  return numeros[indice];
}
```